# Why in the output I am getting value as list

Tags: python

I have converted the nested loop into dictionary.
Here is the nested list.

```
score = [['hamza', 30], ['ali', 20], ['abdul',50]]
```

I have converted this into dict with this code.

```
my_dict = { k[0]: k[1:] for k in score}
```

Here is the output.

```
{'hamza': [30], 'ali': [20], 'abdul': [50]}
```

Why in the values are inside the list.

Is there anyway to get the values without list.

Comment: `k[1:]` -> `k[1]`

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax `k[1:]` means "Give me a list of all the elements in `k`, starting from element `1` and going all the way to the end".

Just leave the `:` away and you'll get what you want.